# Java Encrypt String where encrypted string and original string with same length

Tags: java, encryption

Could you please share a working example of encryption using Java where encrypted string and the orginal string length is always the same?

Or you can share the algorithm as well.

Comment: You can use a stream cipher as ChaCha20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This algorithm is called "One Time Pad" See here:

[One time pad, encryption and decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187652/one-time-pad-encryption-and-decryption)

And here: [One time pad, encryption and decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187652/one-time-pad-encryption-and-decryption)

It uses a key that has the same length as the encrypted message.